# Передача данных в массив

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы

Имеется цикл, который считывает строки из БД по очереди.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    name = reader["GIVENNAME"].ToString();
    lastname = reader["LASTNAME"].ToString();
    email = reader["PERSON_EMAIL"].ToString();
}
```

А также имеется массив (не уверен, что это называется массив):

```
new TableContent("Persons")
    .AddRow(
        new FieldContent("Name", "Eric"),
        new FieldContent("Lastname", "Davidych"),
        new FieldContent("Email", "davidych@gmail.com"))
    .AddRow(
        new FieldContent("Name", "Dimka"),
        new FieldContent("Lastname", "Zaicev"),
        new FieldContent("Email", "zaicev@gmail.com"))
);
```

В котором `Name` – это фиксированное название поля, в которое я передаю переменную.

Требуется сделать так, чтобы при каждой итерации цикла While, в массив добавлялось новое "AddRow" со значениями из While.

Comment: Ну так....эм.... объявите до цикла переменную `TableContent tableContent =  new TableContent("Persons")` а в конце цикла пишите `tableContent.AddRow(new FieldContent("Name", name),
                        new FieldContent("Lastname", lastname),
                        new FieldContent("Email", email));`

Answer (score 3):

```
var cont = new TableContent("Persons");
while (reader.Read())
{
   name = reader["GIVENNAME"].ToString();
   lastname = reader["LASTNAME"].ToString();
   email = reader["PERSON_EMAIL"].ToString();

   cont.AddRow(
        new FieldContent("Name", name),
        new FieldContent("Lastname", lastname),
        new FieldContent("Email", email)
    );
}
```